# Jupyter notebook on VsCode not accepting JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have python and jupyter notebook installed on my VsCode editor.

I am interested in running a JavaScript snippet on the Jupyter Notebook VsCode editor. For some reason, this is giving me an error

[image]

I am not sure what is going wrong and I understand why such a simple code does not want to run?

I am following the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTco1nTTlzE&t=129s)

Comment: The video shows `%%js` at the start of the cell containing JavaScript code. If you don't include that cell magic, the Python kernel will assume you are trying to run Python code.

Comment: @joyceerhl even if you included this it does not work! :s

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure to install `ijavascript` kernel on your system:
[iJavaScirpt Installation process](https://n-riesco.github.io/ijavascript/doc/install.md.html)

On VSCode you can change your notebook's kernel:

[image: Select Kernel Button]

Select the `ijavascript` kernel from your list of Kernels:

[image: Kernel List choices]

Lastly, you can execute your `JavaScript` code:

[image: JS Cell execution example]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `%%js` before your JS code.